# Email to Case: mail tracked?

Tags: email2case

Suppose that I have a Case x with a *mail submitter* field. Does Salesforce track the mails sent between the Service Cloud user and the "submitter"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a mail is sent to your support mail it becames a Case thank to the Email-to-Case. If the User contacts the mail submitter it is tracked by Salesforce with a certain ID (called **ThreadID**) that you have to enable in *Setup* - *Customize* - *Case* - *Email to Case*. In that way under the specific Case you can see all the mails exchanged.